# What are best practices when designing navigation menu, page titles and breadcrumb of a list of items and the related pages to add/edit/remove items?

Tags: navigation, lists

I'm trying to design a desktop application that let the users list strategies and add/edit/delete a strategy.

- To add a new strategy the user will find a menu in the listing page.
- To edit and delete an existing strategy, the user will find small icons aligned right in the list rows, and also at the top of the strategy's detailed page.

I have a specific question and a more general one.

- Regarding the title of the detailed item page. Should the title (name of the item) remains the same when the user navigates through the navigation menu Feature 1, Feature 2, Settings? Or should I add a subtitle with the name of the active menu?
- More generally I would appreciate if someone could point me to an article with the best practices to design these pages, menu and breadcrumbs.

This is what I did:

**Breadcrumbs**

Listing page:

```
Strategies
```

Detailed item page:

```
Strategies / Strat_001
```

Add an item page:

```
Strategies / Add New
```

**Vertical menu**

Listing page:

```
GENERAL
- All strategies
- Add new
```

Detailed item page:

```
STRATEGY
- Feature 1
- Feature 2
- Feature 3
- Settings
```

**Page titles**

Listing page:

```
All Strategies
```

Detailed item page:

```
Strat_001
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm... quite a few questions here, more context might help - I assume this is for a desktop app, not mobile? Is "Strategies" your top level page (in which case you would likely not list it in the breadcrumb, only once they have drilled in a page)? What does the actual site hierarchy or map look like?

In the meantime, however, here are two good over-arching articles about how to best leverage breadcrumbs:

https://www.nngroup.com/articles/breadcrumbs/

https://uxplanet.org/a-quick-guide-to-breadcrumb-navigation-why-do-breadcrumbs-matter-for-seo-fb7acb4134d4